# keeping the best string matched by fuzzy matching in R

Tags: r, string, string-matching, fuzzyjoin

I have two dataframes in R. one a dataframe of the phrases I want to match along with their synonyms in another column (**df.word**), and the other a data frame of the strings I want to match along with codes (**df.string**). The strings are complicated but to make it easy say we have:

```
df.word <- data.frame(label = c('warm wet', 'warm dry', 'cold wet'),
                 synonym = c('hot and drizzling\nsunny and raining','sunny and clear sky\ndry sunny day', 'cold winds and raining\nsnowing'))

df.string <- data.frame(day = c(1,2,3,4),
                       weather = c('there would be some drizzling at dawn but we will have a hot day', 'today there are cold winds and a bit of raining or snowing at night', 'a sunny and clear sky is what we have today', 'a warm dry day'))
```

I want to create df.string$extract in which I want to have **the best match** available for the string.

a column like this

```
df$extract <- c('warm wet', 'cold wet', 'warm dry', 'warm dry')
```

thanks in advance for anyone helping.

Comment: actually the best match would be the longest match ... the one with the most number of words detected in the string.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few points that I did not quite understand in your question; however, I am proposing a solution for your question. Check whether it will work for you.

I assume that you want to find the best-matching labels for the weather texts. If so, you can use `stringsim` function from `library(stringdist)` in the following way.

First Note: If you clean the `\n` in your data, the result will be more accurate. So, I clean them for this example, but if you want you can keep them.

Second Note: You can change the similarity distance based on the different methods. Here I used cosine similarity, which is a relatively good starting point. If you want to see the alternative methods, please see the reference of the function:

```
?stringsim
```

The clean data is as follow:

```
df.word <- data.frame(
    label = c("warm wet", "warm dry", "cold wet"),
    synonym = c(
        "hot and drizzling sunny and raining",
        "sunny and clear sky dry sunny day", 
        "cold winds and raining snowing"
    )
)

df.string <- data.frame(
    day = c(1, 2, 3, 4),
    weather = c(
        "there would be some drizzling at dawn but we will have a hot day",
        "today there are cold winds and a bit of raining or snowing at night", 
        "a sunny and clear sky is what we have today", 
        "a warm dry day"
    )
)
```

Install the library and load it

```
install.packages('stringdist')
library(stringdist)
```

Create a `n x m` matrix that contains the similarity scores for each whether text with each synonym. The rows show each whether text and the columns represent each synonym group.

```
match.scores <- sapply(          ## Create a nested loop with sapply
    seq_along(df.word$synonym),  ## Loop for each synonym as 'i'
    function(i) {
        sapply(
            seq_along(df.string$weather), ## Loop for each weather as 'j'
            function(j) {
                stringsim(df.word$synonym[i], df.string$weather[j], ## Check similarity 
                    method = "cosine", ## Method cosine  
                    q = 2 ## Size of the q -gram: 2 
                )
            }
        )
    }
)

r$> match.scores
          [,1]      [,2]       [,3]
[1,] 0.3657341 0.1919924 0.24629819
[2,] 0.6067799 0.2548236 0.73552828
[3,] 0.3333974 0.6300619 0.21791793
[4,] 0.1460593 0.4485426 0.03688556
```

Get the best matches across the rows for each whether text, find the labels with the highest matching scores, and add these labels to the data frame.

```
ranked.match <- apply(match.scores, 1, which.max)
df.string$extract <- df.word$label[ranked.match]

df.string

r$> df.string
  day                                                             weather  extract
1   1    there would be some drizzling at dawn but we will have a hot day warm wet
2   2 today there are cold winds and a bit of raining or snowing at night cold wet
3   3                         a sunny and clear sky is what we have today warm dry
4   4                                                      a warm dry day warm dry
```

Comment: Thank you for your complete explanation and answer. I tried the code with different "q"s ... the best was with q=5 but still less than half were correct... I want all the words of the labels/synonyms to be present but this does not happen with any method or q (I mean that for example I even get a "warm dry" label for a "snowing" weather).

Comment: this would have been fine.. [link] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62411327/how-to-extract-all-matching-patterns-words-in-a-string-in-a-dataframe-column) but the problem with this is that in this case I only want the best answer not all matches.

Comment: I see. Could you please submit an example of end work. Thus, I can get a better sense of what you want exactly.  What would you like to see in the extracted column? If you do not mind giving an example.

Comment: I dont mind except that the text is in persian language.... it is actually text of the temperaments for some herbs in a traditional medical text... for example I have a herb which is hot in second degree and wet in third degree and what I need is "hot wet" ... or like a drug which "is balanced with slight hotness and dry in first degree" for which I need the label "balanced hot dry" ... but I with the code above I have the label **balanced hot dry** for a drug which only says a short sentence "it's dry". I don't know where the **balanced** and **hot** have come from.